# Animate view added on WindowManager

Tags: android, android-animation, window-managers

I have a view (customView) added to the WindowManager.

```
WindowManager mWm = (WindowManager)activity.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0, PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
mWl.dimAmount = 0.0f;
mWm.addView(customView, mWl);
```

Inside the custom view, I will call a translate animation when close button is pressed.

//// This is the handler for the animation ////

```
final Handler translateHandler = new Handler();

final Runnable mtranslateUp = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Log.v("TEST","mtranslateUp Runnable");
        startAnimation(translateUp);
    }
};
```

//// This is the listener for the close button////

```
View.OnClickListener closeButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {         

    public void onClick(View v) {
        translateHandler.post(mtranslateUp);
    }
};
```

//// This is the translate up animation ////

```
translateUp = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,-200);
translateUp.setFillAfter(true);
translateUp.setDuration(1000);
translateUp.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            Log.v("TEST","translateUp onAnimationEnd");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            Log.v("TEST","translateUp onAnimationStart");
        }}
    );
```

If the customView is added to an activity, these code works fine!

When the customView is added to a WindowManager, the Log inside the onAnimationStart didn't show but the Log inside the Runnable can be shown.

Can anybody tells how to do animation on a view that is added to the WindowManager?

Comment: Have you got any solution for this?  Please share, I am also facing same issue

Answer (score 11):

You should animate the view LayoutParameters. For example I use a method to update the view layout:

```
    public void updateViewLayout(View view, Integer x, Integer y, Integer w, Integer h){
    if (view!=null) {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

        if(x != null)lp.x=x;
        if(y != null)lp.y=y;
        if(w != null && w>0)lp.width=w;
        if(h != null && h>0)lp.height=h;

        mWindowService.updateViewLayout(view, lp);
    }
}
```

Obviously **mWindowService** is context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE).
I trigger this method in the animation:

```
    public static void overlayAnimation(final View view2animate, int viewX, int endX) {
    ValueAnimator translateLeft = ValueAnimator.ofInt(viewX, endX);
    translateLeft.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            updateViewLayout(view2animate, val, null, null, null);

        }
    });
    translateLeft.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
    translateLeft.start();
}
```

Comment: Cool, this is the way to do it right without wrapping view into ViewGroup

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, thanks! I tried using TranslateAnimation but no dice.

Answer (score 8):

I was facing similar problem with a View attached to WindowManager.Try adding ViewGroup to WindoManager than View directly. It should work.

Comment: You mean add the view to a viewgroup and then add the viewgroup to windowmanager?

Comment: @alex how did you solve? I included an `ImageView` inside a `FrameLayout`, but now when I animate my `ImageView`, it goes off the bounds of the `FrameLayout`, so it is not visible anymore

Answer (score 0):

`windowManager` need a animation by android system. so the custom animation will not work

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem.

When i use updateViewLayout in onAnimationUpdate, and i set the LayoutParams's width, the animation has dropped frames.

But i set the LayoutParams's x or y, the animation is ok.

like the below code:

```
        mViewWidth = 800;
        mViewHeight = 800;
        final int oldX = mFloatWindowParams.x;
        final int oldWidth = mFloatWindowParams.width;
        final int oldHeight = mFloatWindowParams.height;
        final int deltaWidth = mViewWidth - oldWidth;
        final int deltaHeight = mViewHeight - oldHeight;
        final boolean isWidthLarger = deltaWidth > deltaHeight;
        int first = isWidthLarger ? oldWidth : oldHeight;
        int end = isWidthLarger ? mViewWidth : mViewHeight;
        ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(first, end);

        va.setDuration(1000);
        va.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                int value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                float fraction = animation.getAnimatedFraction();
                Log.i("onAnimationUpdate", value + "");
                if (isWidthLarger) {
                    mFloatWindowParams.width = value;
                    mFloatWindowParams.height = oldHeight + (int) (deltaHeight * fraction);
                } else {
                    mFloatWindowParams.width = oldWidth + (int) (deltaWidth * fraction);
                    mFloatWindowParams.height = value;
                }
                mFloatWindowParams.x = oldX - (int) (deltaWidth * fraction);

                mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mRootView, mFloatWindowParams);
            }
        });
        va.start();
```